# Redux word for a function that changes state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In redux, what would you call a function within the switch statement for a particular action that takes state as a parameter, changes it and returns a new state?

```
function reducer(state = DEFAULT_STATE, action) {
  let count = state.count
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_COLOR:
      return { color: action.color }
    case UPDATE_LANGUAGE:
      return updateLanguage(state, action)
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

In the function above what kind of function would `updateLanguage` be?

Comment: Why would that change anything? Maybe I'm missing something but I believe it would still be called a reducer, as it has the same exact functionality as a reducer, you should use combine reducers here...http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html

Comment: Redux maintains the state for each reducer, so `updateLanguage` is just an ordinary function and has no reducer map on the redux store.

Comment: but it has the same exact functionality of a reducer in terms of inputs and outputs yet it because it isn't found on the state it isn't a reducer anymore? Dan calls it a 'child reducer' in the link you posted below...semantics perhaps

Comment: Man, you don't like marking questions as answered, eh? http://stackoverflow.com/users/340688/thomasreggi?tab=questions&sort=newest Good to know, makes me think twice ;-)

Comment: @lux Just fixed that. Wen't wayyyy back and approved a ton of questions. Thanks for the kick in the rear!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're passing `state` and `action`, you've actually just created another [reducer](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html), assuming you return a new `state`:

```
type Reducer<S, A> = (state: S, action: A) => S
```

And the act of splitting work into smaller reducers is a widely used pattern in Redux - or from the docs, if you prefer:

> This is called reducer composition, and it’s the fundamental pattern of building Redux apps.

Take a peek at [this example](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html) - and we can see the `Todos` and `Todo` reducer, where each handles a chunk of state and a particular action. Please note that the `Todo` reducer only handles one `todo` object. And this is often the case: you'll often want to pass a smaller chunk of the `state` to a sub-reducer, and not all of `state`.

However, that said, the beauty of Redux is that you can write your reducers however you'd like. The only stipulations are that your reducer function must accept `state` and an `action`, and that it must return a *new* `state` object.

Comment: Isn't this only a reducer if you actually return a name reference (e.g.: object key, named export), as mentioned in https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/428#issuecomment-129223274

Comment: @MattLo Good question. You'll only need to export the reducer if you need to include it in `combineReducers`, otherwise it wouldn't be available. Other than that, a reducer (in pure Redux terms), is simply a function that accepts `state` and an `action` and returns a new `state`. Per the docs, here's a more fancy representation: `type Reducer<S, A> = (state: S, action: A) => S`

Answer (score 0):

You would call it a reducer or a pure function.

> The reducer is a pure function that takes the previous state and an action, and returns the next state.

Source: [Handling Actions](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/basics/Reducers.md#handling-actions)